# Cómo puedo hacer que se cumplan una función en mi Form1 luego de que se cierre el MessageBox?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código que es para que cuando se presione un botón surja la función de que se genere el texto de los botones y aparezca el texto en el `richTextBox`, pero quiero que surja la función luego de que se muestre el `MessageBox`.

Estos son los métodos que cumplen con la función de generar el texto de los botones y el `richTextBox`.

```
  private void AsignarCitaBtn()
  {
        while (botones.Count != 0)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int index = rnd.Next(botones.Count);
            txtBtns.Add(botones[index]);
            botones.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        Btn.Text = txtBtns[0];
        Btn2.Text = txtBtns[1];
        Btn3.Text = txtBtns[2];
        Btn4.Text = txtBtns[3];
        Btn5.Text = txtBtns[4];
        Btn6.Text = txtBtns[5];

        txtBtn = Btn.Text;
        txtBtn2 = Btn2.Text;
        txtBtn3 = Btn3.Text;
        txtBtn4 = Btn4.Text;
        txtBtn5 = Btn5.Text;
        txtBtn6 = Btn6.Text;

 }

 private void EscogerCita()
 {
        while (citas.Count != 0)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            index = random.Next(citas.Count);
            cita = citas[index];
            richTextBox1.Text = cita;
            citas.RemoveAt(index);   
 }
```

Entonces este es el botón que quiero oprimir para que se cumplan las funciones si se cumple con las condiciones, pero primero quiero que se muestre y cierre el MessageBox y luego se cumpla con el método de EscogerCita y AsignarCitaBtn.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (txtBtn == "Filipenses 4:13" && "Todo lo puedo en Cristo." == richTextBox1.Text) {
        MessageBox.Show("Muy Bien!!!");
        puntos = +5;
        label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
        EscogerCita();
        AsignarCitaBtn();
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Estas Mal!!");
    }
    EscogerCita();
    AsignarCitaBtn();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconozco que se pueda identificar cuando se cierra o no un MessageBox, pero te recomiendo que ocupes un `DialogResult`

```
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Muy bien!!!", "",  MessageBoxButtons.OK);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    puntos = +5;
    label1.Text = "Puntos:" + Convert.ToString(puntos);
    EscogerCita();
    AsignarCitaBtn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar `DialogResult`. Sigue la [documentacion de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) para hacer lo que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Ya tiene una respuesta válida , pero quisiera añadir una recomendacion y una opción más

- Para la comparación  de `String` use [Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) **(mejor)** Usando el método Statico si no podría presentarse una `Exceptión` como lo mencionó @sstan cuando lo del lado izquierdo sea `null`

  ```
  if (String.Equals(txtBtn,"Filipenses 4:13") && 
       String.Equals("Todo lo puedo en Cristo.",richTextBox1.Text) {
  ```
- El MessageBox Puede ser así.

  ```
  if(MessageBox.Show("Mensaje a Mostrar", "Titulo del MessageBox",
   MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)==DialogResult.Yes)
   {
     /* Tareas luego que el Usuario Dió click sobre el Boton Yes del MessageBox*/
      EscogerCita();
      AsignarCitaBtn();
   }
  ```

Comment: ¿Por qué es mucho mejor usar `Equals`?  En C# se acostumbra usar el `==` para comparar strings, y eso está bien. De hecho evita problemas si el string de la izquierda es `null`. Por supuesto, en Java por ejemplo, la cosa es muy diferente.

Comment: @sstan Por lo que yo sabia `Equals` sirve mucho más para comparar objetos y valores, mientras que si queremos comparar un valor podemos utilizar tanto `Equals` como `==`, en fin, parece ser que ambas son validas

Comment: @sstan Tienes mucha razón , me olvidaba de la `NullPointerException` , se puede mitigar usando el método `Equals` Estático de la clase `String` . Gracias por la Observación

Comment: Veo que también manejas Java (no es `NullPointerException` en C#, si no `NullReferenceException`), puede que de allí venga la idea que tuvistes. Pero, en lo personal, no recomendaría `Equals` como una mejor opción para comparar strings en C#. Otro detalle: si se llegara a usar el `Equals` con un string, no sería el del enlace que tienes, si no este: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: De paso, ¡felicitationes en alcanzar 2000 rep!

Comment: Gracias. es buena la interacción que se da en estos casos , Ayuda para bien siempre. Gracias por las Observaciones.